# JQuery to show the Primefaces's confirmDialog

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

**How to use JQuery to show the Primefaces's confirmDialog ?**

Comment: Why using JQuery when you already have a client side api to call the confirm dialog to show or hide?

Comment: Some time, we need to control the dialog.When user modify some place, we need to show. And Other conditions, we don't need it.So I use JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Primefaces dialogs have javascript convenience methods for showing and hiding.

```
// where dialog is the widgetVar of your Primefaces dialog.
dialog.show();
dialog.hide();
```

For many of the Primefaces components however you can access the underlying jQuery object by looking for a property jq.

```
component.jq.removeClass('exampleClass');
```

Above is an example.

Comment: jQuery(document)
     .ready(
       function() {
        $("#queuePriorityForm:moveUpButton").click(function(){
         confirmation.show();
           });
       }
        );

Comment: Because I want to show the dialog when users selects another tab without saving the request.

Comment: @maple_shaft:you can see my another question

Comment: @maple_shaft:I am Chinese.So I sleep last night.Because I won't write JQuery .The JQuery I writed can't run.It show the complie error :Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Comment: I think I might understand your problem now, the '$' symbol cannot be used with jQuery in a Primefaces/JSF project because it is a reserved character. Instead of `$('#DOMElementId')` try doing this instead, `jQuery('#DOMElementId')`.  This is the long form version of `$`